# Cardinality of subsets with fixed cardinal of a set

Tags: cardinals

Let $\lambda\leq\kappa$ be infinite cardinals.
Then $| \{X\subset \kappa | |X|=\lambda \} | = \kappa^{\lambda} $

$\leq$ part is trivial, but I don't know how to prove the other part. I used transfinite induction on $\lambda$ but it didn't work to me. Can I have any hint for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One of *many* duplicates.

Comment: Can I have a link? I couldn't find any..